# ROLLUP on only 1 column in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, rollup

I understand that we can use ROLLUP to get the total sum in group by query.
However, is it possible to have more than 1 group by columns in group by query, but ROLLUP can be applied to ONLY ONE column ?

eg, default ROLLUP behaviour:

```
SELECT year, country, product, SUM(profit) 
FROM sales
GROUP BY year, country, product WITH ROLLUP

| 2000 | USA     | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2000 | USA     | NULL       |        1575 |
| 2000 | NULL    | NULL       |        4525 |
```

Required Output (applying `RollUp` on 3rd column, but `group by` on 3rd as well as 2nd column) :

```
| 2000 | USA     | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2000 | USA     | NULL       |        1575 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use having to limit the output.
In your case, just put

`having country is not null`

Comment: This does limit the output, but you still burn computation time on the rollups you didn't want to do.  I ended up here because of rollups on several columns that produced very large intermediary sets and can't just filter after the fact due to performance implications (and `having` doesn't kick in until after rollups have occurred).